# How to incorporate StreamBuilder into a SliverList?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a StreamBuilder to fetch data, then passing it onto a ListView.builder to populate the list. Now I want to add a SliverAppBar to have a collapsing AppBar as I scroll down the list.

How can I incorporate my listview builder into a CustomScrollView sliver? Or do I convert my ListView.builder into a SliverListView? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you add your source code little bit?